# Server configuration automation for windows server on ec2, how much can be done?

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, configuration-management

I believe stackexchange runs on IIS and windows server.

I understand windows server doesn't have anything similiar to chef/puppet, but it does have powershell and probably other things I am not aware of.

How much configuration management can be done on a windows server so I could fire up a ec2 instance and run scripts to get the server configurated.

Configured in terms of:

1. patches/updates
2. IIS settings
3. setup a asp.net application in IIS
4. turn on/off services that I need/don't need

Note: this is a pure web server, so basically just need to setup a IIS website, turn of unwatned services, get the o/s up to date with patches etc.

(Other than configuring a front end web server and then creating a custom AMI)

Comment: I'd be curious to know which way you ended up deciding to go. I've been doing this for over two years now and agree with you that the open source solutions are limited and therefore the services I've linked to below. Still always interested in ow others are solving the same issues

Comment: didn't end up going just yet, still confused :)

Comment: just a quick note: Chef and Puppet can now manage windows servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

You can do all of the above using [RightScale's](https://www.rightscale.com/s/create-account.php?sd=Free) free developer account and infact that's what I do for a living; focus on building Windows solutions on public clouds.

[Here (revised link)](https://wiki.opscode.com/display/ChefCN/Installation+on+Windows) is some information on running a chef client on Windows and you could probably test this using the [hosted chef](http://www.opscode.com/hosted-chef/) solution opscode provides free for under 5 nodes.

Use [Cloudformation](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/09/powerful-new-features-for-aws-cloudformation.html) by Amazon Web Services

[Kaavo](http://www.kaavo.com) also offers a service that allows configuration management of your cloud instances and works with Windows

Roll your own using Powershell remoting but probably not worth the pain.

DISCLAIMER: I work for RightScale.

Comment: Was Powershell Desired State Configuration designed to accomplish the same thing?  It's something new in PS 4.0 that I'm beginning to study.

Answer (score 0):

Within 30 minutes or less for all the above. I just did what you said and configured a sql server today.

Use an ami that comes with IIS and ASP.NET and launch. Takes few minutes. You will wait 5 min to get your windows password for remote login.

Then you login remotely and run updates/patches.  Configure IIS and upload your app.

Ameer has mentioned a good option too but I'm a do it myself kind of guy. I like to waste time in trying to figure out stupid stuff.